# Navigation arrow is not displayed properly using settings_ui

Tags: flutter

I use Flutter and settings_ui 2.0.2 and developing settings screen.

In iOS simulator and device, navigation arrow is now displayed properly as belows.

[image]

Here is the current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:settings_ui/settings_ui.dart';

...

SettingsSection(
              title: const Text('Application'),
              tiles: <SettingsTile>[
                SettingsTile.navigation(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.reviews),
                  title: const Text('Review'),
                ),
                SettingsTile.navigation(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
                  title: const Text('Inquiry by Email'),
                    onPressed: (context) => _launchMailer(),
                ),
                SettingsTile.navigation(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.share),
                  title: const Text('Share with your friends'),
                ),
                SettingsTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.settings_applications),
                  title: const Text('App version'),
                  value: const Text('1.0'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone(beginner) got the same situation.

I was commented out `cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2` below.

```
# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```